# How to group matches together that are in a value range and check results?

Tags: r, data.table, bioinformatics

I have a genetic dataset where I am grouping gene variants that are physically close together in the genome. I group genes that are a 500 +/- distance from certain spots in the genome per chromosome.

I've coded for this, however, when I look at my output, my newly formed  `group` column isn't making groups starting from number 1, the lowest-numbered group is 5 and I can't figure out why.

My 'spots' dataset is of positions that variants need to be within 500 +/- range of and looks like:

```
connected_spots     chrom          min          max      low       high
    1                1             1000         1200     500       1700
    2                1             20000        20100    19500     20600
    3                5             900          1000     400       1500
```

The `low` and the `high` columns are the range I am looking to collect variants in. They are created by being +500 or -500 the `max` and `min` values with:

```
spots[, c("low", "high") := .(min - 500, max  + 500)]
```

I then compare if my second dataset, df, has any variants (rows) in a position in the genome that are within the range of `low` and `high` and group them together into a `group` column if the variants are in range of the same spot:

```
df$connected_spots <- seq.int(nrow(df))

#Find matches in df on matching chromosomes and position between low&high:

df <- df[spots, group := i.connected_spots, on = .(chrom, position > low, position < high ) ]
```

My df that I'm looking to see if any gene variants fit in the range of the spots looks like:

```
Gene   chrom position connected_spots
Gene1   1    1200           1
Gene2   1    10000          2
Gene3   5    500            3
```

I pre-create a `connected_spots` column for df just to give each variant/row an ID to be picked up on for searching the position matching - is this actually problematic to do if I am ultimately searching for which variant is in `connect_spots` range in my first dataset? What would cause my real data to have the lowest `group` be 5?

So the output I'm getting (when I sort groups lowest to highest) is:

```
Gene   chrom position     group
Gene4   1    1200           5
Gene8   1    10000          5
Gene9   5    500            6
```

Why doesn't `group` start with group 1?

Is there another way I can code this line:

```
df <- df[spots, group := i.connected_spots, on = .(chrom, position > low, position < high ) ]
```

to potentially avoid the problems I'm having with my real data?

Input data:

```
#Spots dataset:

structure(list(connected_spots = 1:3, chrom = c(1L, 1L, 5L), 
    min = c(1000L, 20000L, 900L), max = c(1200L, 20100L, 1000L
    ), low = c(500L, 19500L, 400L), high = c(1700L, 20600L, 1500L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

#Variants to find in range of spots:

structure(list(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3"), chrom = c(1L, 
1L, 5L), position = c(1200L, 10000L, 500L), connected_spots = 1:3), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: A: matching criteria. Filter datasets to single group smaller than 5, and then do join relaxing join conditions so see which condition eliminates rows from results.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and sorry I've worded my question a bit poorly, it' not that there aren't less than 5 genes in a group, but that groups 1-4 don't exist at all - I've updated my question

Comment: If they don't exist then you shouldn't expect them to be matched during join. You may want to reverse operation and to right join rather than left join. Or full join if you need not matched rows from both tables.

Comment: Is this a problem where data.table::groupingsets could be useful? Or just the base 'grouping' ?